# Search a specific substring in array of strings

Tags: python

I'm a newcomer to python so I just can't understand how to solve my task :(

I have a simple code that scans folders and sub-folders for files and puts their name in an array.

```
import os

files = []
folders = []
for (path, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('Folder'):
    folders.extend(os.path.join(path, name) for name in dirnames)
    files.extend(os.path.join(path, name) for name in filenames)
files.sort()
folders.sort()
print (files)
print (folders)
```

in these folders there will be lots of files with basically one pattern of naming, exmaple below:

```
SMTH-SMTH.SMTH.ver1.ext
SMTH-SMTH.SMTH.ver2.ext
SMTH-SMTH.SMTH.ver3.ext
```

I need to scan this array somehow and choose between those files the one with the biggest **ver.** number and then just put the results in another array, few I'm trying and I fail. Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is a Q&A site. You have to ask a good question.

Comment: the question is obvious

Comment: Can you show us what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

In your case better solution is to use the fnmatch module. Please google it

https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html

What you can do in case of matching --> use re module https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

If you have access to each file_name after the scanning part as you showed, then it should be easier to make a matching on those files.

Additionally if your file is in the for C://Folder_Name/Folder/file_name you can use the os module to get only the file name with os.path.basename(file)

Comment: Thanks alot Marco, i got the basic idea ill report here what i will get in result ! Cheers

Comment: Always welcome :-) Hope I could help a bit :-) Have a nice day.